# Click gets fired twice in AngularJS Module

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have the following html:

```
<div ng-repeat="email in user.emails" class="form-group">
            <label for="inputEmail_{{$index+1}}" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Email {{$index+1}}</label>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-xs-11">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail_{{$index+1}}" name="inputEmail_{{$index+1}}" placeholder="Email" required>
            </div>
            <div ng-if="$index == 0" class="col-lg-1 col-xs-1">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info addEmailBtn" ng-click="addEmailInput()">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div ng-if="$index != 0" class="col-lg-1 col-xs-1">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="removeEmailInput($index)">
                    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And my controller is:

```
module.controller('NewContactCtrl',
function EditProfileController($scope) {

    $scope.user = {
        emails: [
            { emailValue: "" }
        ]
    };


    $scope.addEmailInput = function () {
        $scope.user.emails.push({ emailValue: "" });
    };

    $scope.removeEmailInput = function (index) {
        $scope.user.emails.splice(index, 1);
    };

});
```

And for some reason SOMETIMES when I click `.addEmailBtn`, the click event gets fired twice so I get two new elements instead of one.

EDIT You can reproduce problem here:
http://jsbin.com/qiwehiwico/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Have you got jquery-mobile included? Maybe you are experimenting the phantom click bug

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude no I don't have jquery-mobile included.

Comment: can you repro on plnkr or something

Comment: So the problem seems to be in the `push`. Try this: `scope.user.emails = { emailValue: "" };`

Comment: do console.log in controller to make sure, controller is not initiated twice.

Comment: Or there is more code that you don't share

Comment: This code looks fine to me http://jsbin.com/peguhukela/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Not an answer but worth to note that using bootstrap3 grid system, `col-sm`, `col-md` and `col-lg` will inherit from the `col-xs` if their grid numbers are the same or they are not defined. so the `col-lg` part is redundant.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/qiwehiwico/1/edit?html,js,output here is it with whole form

Comment: @Shyju you should be able to reproduce it on the link above

Comment: @jbojcic even your link works fine for me. Tested in chrome

Comment: @Shyju I am also using chrome and it doesn't happen on every click.